# Angular.JS - Managing different states with same url

Tags: angularjs, state

So here is a much needed requirement i need to implement and i know it should not be this way but this is a requirement i cannot waive off.

So currently i have a webapp of my own which has 3 different urls:

`helloworld.com/en`

`helloworld.com/ar`

`helloworld.com/{coderName}`

Now what i need to do is that when the url is `/en` or `/ar`, it should change the languages of the page which means it has to hit a different state. but whenever there is anything else apart from these two parameters, it should hit the third url i.e. `/{coderName}`.

Usually in node.js we can have routes set up in descending order in this way but how do we tackle this in angular.js?

Comment: Which router does the app use? ngRoute or AngularUI-Router?

Comment: @georgeawg its UI-Router.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a default state, you can use the "[otherwise](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes)". It is not what it supposed to do, but that's something you can use to get what you want.

Here is an example:

```
angular
    .module('your module')
    .config(function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector){
             let $state = $injector.get("$state");
             $state.go('your default state');
        });
}
```